# Bootstrap form-inline DropDownLists with static width

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 3 DropDownLists with Labels inline with each other. I am trying to make all of the DropDown's width to be static 200px. Instead bootstrap is overriding and making it so the dropdowns are always dynamically the width of the widest item inside.

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label ID="lblDropDownList1" runat="server" Text="DDL 1 Label:" AssociatedControlID="ddlDropDownList1"></asp:Label>
        <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="ddlDropDownList1" runat="server" Width="200px" CssClass="form-control"></telerik:RadDropDownList>
    </div>

    <asp:Panel ID="pnlDropDownList2" runat="server" CssClass="form-group" Visible="false">
        <asp:Label ID="lblDropDownList2" runat="server" Text="DDL 2 Label:" AssociatedControlID="ddlDropDownList2"></asp:Label>
        <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="ddlDropDownList2" runat="server" Width="200px" CssClass="form-control"></telerik:RadDropDownList>
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="pnlDropDownList3" runat="server" CssClass="form-group" Visible="false">
        <asp:Label ID="lblDropDownList3" runat="server" Text="DDL 3 Label:" AssociatedControlID="ddlDropDownList3"></asp:Label>
        <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="ddlDropDownList3" Width="200px" CssClass="form-control"></telerik:RadDropDownList>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Make a container DIV with a set width. Then set the width of the drop down to less than that width and it should not overstep the size.